# EKS kube-system deployments CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy Kube State Metrics into the `kube-system` namespace in my EKS Cluster (eks.4) running Kubernetes v1.14.

**Kubernetes Connection**

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = var.cluster.endpoint
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster_auth.token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(var.cluster.certificate)
  load_config_file       = true
}
```

**Deployment Manifest (as .tf)**

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "kube_state_metrics" {
  metadata {
    name      = "kube-state-metrics"
    namespace = "kube-system"

    labels = {
      k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          name  = "kube-state-metrics"
          image = "quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.7.2"

          port {
            name           = "http-metrics"
            container_port = 8080
          }

          port {
            name           = "telemetry"
            container_port = 8081
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/healthz"
              port = "8080"
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 5
            timeout_seconds       = 5
          }

          readiness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = "8080"
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 5
            timeout_seconds       = 5
          }
        }

        service_account_name = "kube-state-metrics"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have deployed all the required RBAC manifests from https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/kubernetes as well - redacted here for brevity.

When I run `terraform apply` on the deployment above, the Terraform output is as follows :
`kubernetes_deployment.kube_state_metrics: Still creating... [6m50s elapsed]`

Eventually timing out at 10m.

Here are the outputs of the logs for the `kube-state-metrics` pod

```
I0910 23:41:19.412496       1 main.go:140] metric white-blacklisting: blacklisting the following items:
W0910 23:41:19.412535       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
W0910 23:41:19.412565       1 client_config.go:546] error creating inClusterConfig, falling back to default config: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
F0910 23:41:19.412782       1 main.go:148] Failed to create client: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided
```

Comment: Is that the only thing logged? That gets logged a fair amount and is a [general warning in the Kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/6924ba6dfc024771f18d50efebb76e0094c01aa3/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go#L549) but is probably not the thing that matters here.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - I have updated to show more log lines.

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following to the `spec` has taken me to a successful deployment.

```
automount_service_account_token = true
```

For posterity :

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "kube_state_metrics" {
  metadata {
    name      = "kube-state-metrics"
    namespace = "kube-system"

    labels = {
      k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          k8s-app = "kube-state-metrics"
        }
      }

      spec {
        automount_service_account_token = true
        container {
          name  = "kube-state-metrics"
          image = "quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.7.2"

          port {
            name           = "http-metrics"
            container_port = 8080
          }

          port {
            name           = "telemetry"
            container_port = 8081
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/healthz"
              port = "8080"
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 5
            timeout_seconds       = 5
          }

          readiness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = "8080"
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 5
            timeout_seconds       = 5
          }
        }

        service_account_name = "kube-state-metrics"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try with terraform.

I have just run this deployment locally i got the same error.

Please run your deployment locally to see the state of your deployment and pods.

```
I0910 13:25:49.632847       1 main.go:140] metric white-blacklisting: blacklisting the following items:
W0910 13:25:49.632871       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.

 and finally:

I0910 13:25:49.634748       1 main.go:185] Testing communication with server
I0910 13:25:49.650994       1 main.go:190] Running with Kubernetes cluster version: v1.12+. git version: v1.12.8-gke.10. git tree state: clean. commit: f53039cc1e5295eed20969a4f10fb6ad99461e37. platform: linux/amd64
I0910 13:25:49.651028       1 main.go:192] Communication with server successful
I0910 13:25:49.651598       1 builder.go:126] Active collectors: certificatesigningrequests,configmaps,cronjobs,daemonsets,deployments,endpoints,horizontalpodautoscalers,ingresses,jobs,limitranges,namespaces,nodes,persistentvolumeclaims,persistentvolumes,poddisruptionbudgets,pods,replicasets,replicationcontrollers,resourcequotas,secrets,services,statefulsets,storageclasses
I0910 13:25:49.651607       1 main.go:226] Starting metrics server: 0.0.0.0:8080
I0910 13:25:49.652149       1 main.go:201] Starting kube-state-metrics self metrics server: 0.0.0.0:8081
```

verification:

```
Connected to kube-state-metrics (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 8080 (#0)
 GET /metrics HTTP/1.1
 Host: kube-state-metrics:8080
 User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
 Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: text/plain; version=0.0.4
 Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2019 13:39:52 GMT
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 [49027 bytes data]
 HELP kube_certificatesigningrequest_labels Kubernetes labels converted to 
Prometheus labels.
```

If you are building own image please follow issues on [gihtub](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/pull/68) and [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/cli-arguments.md)

update: Just to clarify.

AS mentioned in my answer. I didn't try with terraform but it seems that the first question described only one problem `W0910 13:25:49.632871       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.`

So I suggested to run this deployment locally and verify all errors from the logs. Later occurred that there is a problem with `automount_service_account_token`. This important errors wasn't applied to the the original question.
So please follow [terraform issues on github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/263) *how you can manage to solve this problem*

As per [description on github](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/38):

> I spent hours trying to figure out why a service account and deployment wasn't working in Terraform, but worked with no issues in kubectl - it was the AutomountServiceAccountToken being hardcoded to False in the deployment resource.

At a minimum this should be documented in the Terraform docs for the resource with something noting the resource does not behave like kubectl does.

I hope it explains this problem.

Comment: Is this an answer? You appear to be saying you can't reproduce the crash loop when you deploy the same manifest (presumably via kubectl)?

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. I am not building my own image.